# CGRectContainsPoint with object in UIScrollView

Tags: ios

With this code I am trying to detect when a UIbutton moved by the user with his finger is released over another UIButton (or UIImageView):

```
CGPoint dropPoint = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view.superview];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(btn.frame, dropPoint)) { 

....
```

The btn is the UIButton being dragged, while the dropPoint is the location in the view where the user takes away his finger. This method works perfectly if the bnt in in the self.view, but if the btn is in a UIScrollView it doesn't work. How can I make it work even in a UIScrollView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dropPoint` needs to be in the coordinate system of `btn`. Assuming `btn` is a direct subview of `gesture.view.superview`:

```
CGPoint dropPoint = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view.superview];

CGPoint dropPointInBtn = [gesture.view.superview convertPoint:dropPoint toView:btn];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(btn.frame, dropPointInBtn)) { 

....
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. btn is in a UIScrollView on the main view. This code doesn't work...

Comment: But by doing CGPoint dropPointInBtn = [gesture.view.superview convertPoint:dropPoint toView:my scroll view]; works, but not when I slide the scroll view left or right...

Comment: @Alessandro - when the `UIScrollView` is scrolled, use the scroll view's `contentOffset` property to adjust the drop point.